# IonicModal not destroying on calling destroy()

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to destroy ionic modal using angularjs and this is the button code that hides and destroys the modal

```
<button style="border: 3px solid red; border-radius:5px; color: #ff6000" class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="closeNewPost(1);content= '' ">Close</button>
```

// Close the new task modal

```
$scope.closeNewPost = function(index) {
       if (index == 1) {
       $scope.postModal.hide();
        $scope.content = '';

       // $scope.postModal.dismiss();
        alert("another option4");
        $scope.postModal.destroy();

       } else {
         alert("close option 2");
          $scope.selectModal.hide();
       }
```

The above codes hides the modal but never destroys the modal. Please what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to destroy the modal by calling this line of code:

```
 $scope.postModal.remove();
```

But the modal never comes up again unless I refresh the application.

Comment: JnG, I think it does make sense it didn't come up again once you destroyed it from DOM.